# Optional foreign key relationships in EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a project using entity framework and code first. Here are my shortened classes

```
public class BenefitsForm : IAnnualForm, IAuditable 
{
    public BenefitsUser UserInfo { get; set; }
    public CoverageLevel Medical { get; set; } //foreign key to CoverageLevels, optional
}

public class MedicalPlan : IHealthPlan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CoverageLevel> CoverageLevels { get; set; } //list of CoverageLevels, optional
}

public class CoverageLevel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MedicalPlan MedicalPlan { get; set; } //CoverageLevel foreign key to Medical Plan, optional
}
```

So basically a Medical plan has 4 coverage levels each. Each coverage level contains a foreign key reference to the plan that created it (in this case, medical). In addition, each benefit form can contain a specific coverage level (which has a reference to the medical plan).

The end goal is to be able to put a coverage level into benefitsform and also be able to view the medical plan that that coverage level is part of, by doing form.Medical.MedicalPlan. What should my Fluent API look like? This is what I have so far.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CoverageLevel>().HasOptional(c => c.MedicalPlan)
            .WithMany(p => p.CoverageLevels)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.MedicalPlan);
```

What do I need for the BenefitsForm?
Do I need to put a reference to BenefitForm in my CoverageLevel class?

Comment: I find it usefull to include foreign keys in my model. And I like not to use the modelBuilder, and only conventions. With BenefitsForm.Medical, for example (int? is for optionnal) :          public int? CoverageLevelId { get; set; }